# Server can't connect to emit of client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, electron

I have a problem, that I can't connect to socket.emit of Client. Server is on Node.js - Electron. Connection event is working, but it doesn't connect to signIn. And on server it doesn't work with `socket` class, only `io`. Can you help me, please?

Server:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

app.on('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width:800, height: 600})
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
})

var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(client){
  console.log('Socket connection established');
  io.on('signIn', function(message){
    console.log(message);
  });
});



server.listen(3000);
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Client connected');

  socket.emit('signIn', 'coffee');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren’t attaching a listener to the connected socket `client` for the `'signIn'`event. Instead you are attaching it to your Socket Server.

Change your code from

`io.on('signIn', () => {...})`

to

`client.on('signIn', () => {...})`